# How to declare a variable for service_facts

Tags: variables, module, ansible

Below is the sample ansible playbook I use to check the service status using service_facts module and it worked well. Here I need support to define the service name as variable, but when I define it is giving error, VARIABLE NOT DEFINED:

```
---
- name: Check service status
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Service Facts
      service_facts:

    - debug:
        var: ansible_facts.services['firewalld.service']['status']
```

I need "firewalld.service" to be declared under vars section below tasks, tried various options but it is not giving the expected output. I tried below option but it is not working.

```
---
- name: Check service status
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    - SERVICE: firewalld.service
  tasks:
    - name: Service Facts
      service_facts:

    - debug:
        var: ansible_facts.services[SERVICE]['status']
```

Comment: The task should be `debug:
    msg:
      - "{{ ansible_facts.services[SERVICE].status }}"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can run some tasks using [conditionals](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html), for example:

```yaml
  - name: Get service_facts
    service_facts:

  - name: Open some port
    firewalld:
      port: "{{ some_port }}/tcp"
      permanent: yes
      immediate: yes
      offline: no
      state: enabled
    when: 
      - ansible_facts.services['firewalld.service'].state == 'running'
      - ansible_facts.services['firewalld.service'].status == 'enabled'
```

Comment: Sorry, I was requesting for generalizing the task by mentioning  "firewalld.service" in a variable called SERVICE and call the variable in the debug section: ansible_facts.services[SERVICE]['status']

Answer (score 0):

To answer your main question: `vars` expects a dict, not a list:

```
---
- name: Check service status
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    SERVICE: firewalld.service
  tasks:
    - name: Service Facts
      service_facts:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ services[SERVICE]['status'] }}"
```

Additionally you need to use `debug:msg` as others have already mentioned.